# Create bash script for wine cmd script

Tags: shell-script, wine

I have installed FIFA09 through wine & it runs great...however i have to manually go to installation directory each time & open the terminal there. Then have to write in two steps:

`wine cmd`

while cmd is operating in terminal

`FIFA09.exe -Windowed`

how can i chain these commands in a bash script which can then be invoked by a simple .desktop launcher

Comment: Isn't is possible to run `wine /path/to/FIFA09.exe -Windowed` ?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by LatinSuD, this should do the trick:

```
cat > ~/FIFA09.sh << EOF
#!/bin/bash
wine /path/to/FIFA09.exe
EOF
```

Then

```
chmod +x ~/FIFA09.sh
```

And finally this will create an executable bash script in your directory which you can move around at your leisure and execute in directory with ./
Or move it into your path to run it as a normal executable.

Comment: Type it exactly as I have it there.